# Python sshtunnel - How to Validate SSH Connection?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, ssh-tunnel

Using Python, how might I validate that SSH connection is successful after the following:

```
server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    (host_or_ip, 22),
    ssh_username = "ssh_username",
    ssh_private_key = path_to_key,
    remote_bind_address = (another_host_or_ip, 5432)
)

server.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this to see if tunnel is open:

```
server.skip_tunnel_checkup = False
server.start()
server.check_tunnels()
print(server.tunnel_is_up, flush=True)
```

And in the log you will see :

```
{('0.0.0.0', 44004): True}  # this tunnel is up
{('0.0.0.0', 44004): False}  # this tunnel is not up
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using a `try-except`block.

```
ssh_address_or_host = ...    
ssh_username = ... 
ssh_password = ... 
remote_bind_address = ... 

try:
    with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        ssh_address_or_host = ssh_address_or_host,
        ssh_username = ssh_username,
        ssh_password = ssh_password,
        remote_bind_address = remote_bind_address
        ) as server:
        print("connected")

except Exception as e:
    print("Non connected because: " + e)
```

Comment: Hello again, newbie! Let me ask my question a different way. If I create an SSHTunnelForwarder, start it, and receive no exception: is there a way at this point to verify that I have actually successfully connected?

I'm currently reading the _check_tunnel function on sshtunnel github, sshtunnel.py to see how they do it.

I guess I was thinking there might be a simple way to verify connection. "If I can do X, I know the ssh tunnel Y has been successfully established."